# No CSS styling until page reload - cssText is not working

Tags: javascript, css

The new generated list items are not inheriting css styling until the page is reloaded. Styling have been added while it is dynamically being added via cssText but it is not working.

Tried cssText, tried inline Jquery

```
  if (data.success) {
              console.log("Data success");
              // get the data that was returned.
              const contents = `${data.chatroom}`
              // create the dom tree under contacts
              const li = document.createElement('li');
              const div = document.createElement('div');
              const span = document.createElement('span');
              const div0= document.createElement('div')
              const p = document.createElement('p');
              const p0 = document.createElement('p');
              li.classList.add('contact');
              div.classList.add('wrap');
              div0.classList.add('meta');
              p.classList.add('name');
              p0.classList.add('preview');
              // setting innerHTML of new dom tree
              p.innerHTML = contents;
              div0.append(p);
              span.append(div0);
              div.append(span);
              li.append(div);
              var css = {"padding": "15px 0 30px 18px", "display": "block", "cursor": "pointer"};
              li.style.cssText = css;
              document.querySelector('#contacts').appendChild(li);
```

Newly generated list items should have the padding, display, and cursors dynamically generated but nothing is happening.

Comment: Seems to be a JavaScript problem not CSS, please remove CSS from your tags.

Comment: Also, I'm not that good with JavaScript but I believe the problem is with data.success, it'd be nice if you told us if `console.log("Data Success")` is being sent to the console.

Comment: cssText is  not read only... ?

Comment: Thank you everyone, seems that I need to pick up a textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is this is an object

```
var css = {"padding": "15px 0 30px 18px", "display": "block", "cursor": "pointer"};
```

and cssText requires a string - try doing this instead

```
li.style.cssText = "padding: 15px 0 30px 18px; display: block; cursor:pointer";
```

Comment: How do then I add something like :hover? Where can I read to attain this information?

Comment: CSS :hover Selector is part of the CSS and it is not possible to inline CSS style via Javascript this way.  You can however use onmouseover() and onmouseout() events and change the style when the mouse enter / leave the element.

Comment: Thank you. Wow that means even if you have CSS already prebuilt in bootstrap for example, there's no way for the newly created element to inherit the styling during run time or asynchronously? There's so much here that I would like the new element to inherit.

Comment: I got the impression you wanted to create a self-contained Javascript with no CSS file as to why you are using cssText in the first place. If that not the case, then this is the correct way do this. li.style.className = "chatRow"; and have .chatRow {padding: 15px 0 30px 18px; display: block; cursor:pointer} and .chatRow:hover {...} in the CSS file.

Comment: That's what I used but because it is being created through Javascript inside onload through Ajax, these css properties do not apply until the page refreshes, I guess that's why I had to resort to self-contained JS.

Comment: That should not happen. Something is wrong. I meant to say li.className and not li.style.className. Give that a try because it should work.

Comment: I have now ended up cloning the node from the bootstrap template and then just testing if that new exact copy inherits the mouse hover...and it doesn't, again not until it refreshes but the padding and everything else works. I will go back to do some more exercises and see which css selectors will work during runtime, and which ones need JS intervention. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! To learn more efficiently and get better help, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; eg. try to reduce the question to the minimal example still containing the issue; for instance:

- because `data` gets loaded properly, it is just distracting to keep in the question
- the nesting of elements could potentially affect styling, though try with the simplest case first (here, the issue is still there with just 2 instead of 6 nested elements)
- the classes didn't change the result (thus removed for the question)
- provide the required context (in this case the html element added to), so we can run and test the code

```js
const contents = "some text"

const li = document.createElement('li');
const p = document.createElement('p');

p.innerHTML = contents;
li.append(p);

const css = {"background": "red"};
li.style.cssText = css;

document.querySelector('#contacts').appendChild(li);
```

```html
<div id="contacts"></div>
```

Running this snippet, we can see that the contents have been added to the page correctly, though without any styling. Thus, we may conclude that the issue relates to the lines:

```
const css = {"background": "red"};
li.style.cssText = css;
```

With this in mind, we may simplify the question further:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('#contacts')
div.innerText = "should be red"
div.style.cssText = {"background": "red"}
```

```html
<div id="contacts"></div>
```

Now, there are much less moving parts! We now know that `div.style.cssText = {"background": "red"}` contains the issue, because the other lines are working (when running the code, it shows the text "should be red", though it doesn't set the color). We also know that `div` is valid because of the earlier line.

Googling on `cssText`, we can find the documentation:
https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration

> Text of type DOMString The parsable **textual** representation of the
>   declaration block (excluding the surrounding curly braces). Setting
>   this attribute will result in the parsing of the new value and
>   resetting of all the properties in the declaration block including the
>   removal or addition of properties.

In other words, the value should be a string (formatted as in a .css file, or as in `<div style="what: you; write: here;"> ...`) - and not a javascript object.

Applying this change:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('#contacts')
div.innerText = "should be red"
div.style.cssText = "background: red; padding: 20px;"
```

```html
<div id="contacts"></div>
```

...gives us our result! That is, the process of formulating a simpler question often leads to the answer :)

Comment: This is next level programming magic, thank you for clarifying ! Will definitely keep my questions in this format